# Purrr map multiple functions and two inputs

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to use `purrr` to map multiple functions to two inputs. An example is given below but ideally i'd like to extend this to more functions. When trying to do this i'm getting an error that the input is not found, however, even when I try and name  inputs in the list of functions this doesn't rectify the problem.

```
library(yardstick)
library(tidyverse)

funcs <- list(accuracy = yardstick::accuracy_vec,
              recall = yardstick::recall_vec)

n <- 1000
x <- as.factor(rbinom(n, 1, 0.5))
y <- as.factor(rbinom(n, 1, 0.5))

df <- tibble(true = rep(list(y), 3),
             preds = rep(list(x), 3))

df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   true          preds        
#>   <list>        <list>       
#> 1 <int [1,000]> <int [1,000]>
#> 2 <int [1,000]> <int [1,000]>
#> 3 <int [1,000]> <int [1,000]>

df %>% map2_df(.x = true, .y = preds, .f = funcs)
#> Error in map2(.x, .y, .f, ...): object 'true' not found

funcs <- list(accuracy = ~yardstick::accuracy_vec(truth = .x, estimate = .y),
              recall = ~yardstick::recall_vec(truth = .x, estimate = .y))

df %>% map2_df(.x = true, .y = preds, .f = funcs)
#> Error in map2(.x, .y, .f, ...): object 'true' not found
```

Ideally I would end up with something like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  true          preds         accuracy recall
  <list>        <list>           <dbl>  <dbl>
1 <int [1,000]> <int [1,000]>      0.7    0.8
2 <int [1,000]> <int [1,000]>      0.7    0.8
3 <int [1,000]> <int [1,000]>      0.7    0.8
```

Any help is much appreciated, TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested maps:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(map2_dfr(true, preds, ~map_dfc(funcs, do.call, list(.x, .y))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I get errors when I pass numeric values to function `accuracy_vec` and `recall_vec`. I get

> Error: `truth` should be a factor but a integer was supplied..

So I change the data to factor.

```
library(tidyverse)

n <- 1000
x <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)
y <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)

df <- tibble(true = rep(list(factor(y)), 3),
             preds = rep(list(factor(x)), 3))
```

Secondly, pipes pass value from left-hand side (LHS) as first argument to the function on right-hand side. So when you use `df %>% map2_df(.x = true, .y = preds, .f = funcs)` `df` is being passed implicitly.

You may write a custom function to return a tibble.

```
funcs <- function(.x, .y) {
  tibble(accuracy = yardstick::accuracy_vec(truth = .x, estimate = .y), 
         recall =   yardstick::recall_vec(truth = .x, estimate = .y))
}
```

and then use `map2_df` to get one dataframe as output.

```
map2_df(df$true, df$preds, funcs)
```